# Violacion de segmento, problema en punteros o memoria dinamica?

Tags: c++, linux, punteros

Buenas estaba intentando practicar con vectores con memoria dinamica y me ha salido este error al ejecutar:

`Violación de segmento ('core' generado)`

El caso es que a veces funciona, por lo que me deja un poco confundido, este es mi codigo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> // ifstream
using namespace std;

struct VecDin {
   int *datos;
   int n;
};

// FIXME 1: Redimensions v para que se quede con "nuevo" elementos
void ReSize(VecDin& v,int nuevo)
{   
    if(nuevo >= 0) {
        if(nuevo != v.n) {  
            if(nuevo != 0) {
                int *datos_nuevos;
                datos_nuevos = new int[nuevo];
                if(v.n >  0) {
                    int minimo = v.n < nuevo ? v.n : nuevo;
                    for(int i = 0; i < minimo; i++)
                        datos_nuevos[i] = v.datos[i];
                    delete[] v.datos;
                }
                v.datos = datos_nuevos;
                v.n = nuevo;
            }
            else {
                delete[] v.datos;
                v.datos = 0;
                v.n = 0;
            }   
        }
    }

}

// FIXME 2: Lee objetos int hasta final de flujo y devuelve VecDin con los  datos (usa ReSize)
VecDin LeerVecDin(istream& flujo)
{
    VecDin v;
    int n = 1;

    while(flujo.good()) {
        ReSize(v,n);
        flujo >> v.datos[n-1];
        ++n;
    }
    return v;
}

// FIXME 3: Muestra en un flujo de salida los datos enteros de un VecDin     (ver main)

void Mostrar(VecDin vector, ostream& os)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < vector.n || !os.good(); i++)
        os << vector.datos[i] << " ";
}

// FIXME 3: Libera la memoria reservada en un VecDin (ver main)

void Liberar(VecDin v)
{
    delete[] v.datos;
    v.n = 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   VecDin v= {0,0};

   if (argc==1)
      v= LeerVecDin(cin);
   else {
      ifstream f(argv[1]);
      if (!f) {
         cerr << "Error: Fichero " << argv[1] << " no válido." << endl;
         return 1;
      }
      v= LeerVecDin(f);
   }

   Mostrar(v,cout);
   Liberar(v); // Libera la memoria reservada
}
```

Si me pudieran dar una pista de porque, como supongo que es lo que pasa, accede fuera de la memoria que le corresponde me ayudarían muchisimo.

Gracias!

Comment: Para apurar mas , podrías poner salidas de texto con fflush(stdout) en tu main para ver donde se queda pillado. De todos modos segmentation error , significa que estas accediendo a partes de la memoria que no tienes reservada, eso que quiere decir que si accedes a una memoria que no es de otra cosa te va a dar error, si no le ha asignado a otro metodo no lo dará por eso a veces te tira y otras veces no

Comment: he estado probando y claramente el fallo debe estar en la funcion leer o en su defecto, lo que veo mas probable, en ReSize. Aunque sigo sin encontrar el error en el uso de la memoria

Comment: @Ramosaurio `endl` ya hace ese `fflush` que comentas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
VecDin LeerVecDin(istream& flujo)
{
    VecDin v; // (1)
    int n = 1;

    while(flujo.good()) {
        ReSize(v,n); // (2)
        flujo >> v.datos[n-1];
        ++n;
    }
    return v;
}
```

Vamos a analizar esta función:

1. ¿Cuanto valen `v.datos` y , `v.n`? Como no has declarado un constructor para `VecDin` y tampoco le has dado un valor concreto podemos afirmar que el puntero `v.datos` apunta a una dirección aleatoria (=basura) y que el valor de `v.n` es igualmente aleatorio.
2. ¿Como se comporta la función `Resize` ante esta situación? Si revisas la función verás que hay dos caminos que intentan liberar la memoria reservada por `v.n`. Como no existirá tal reserva de memoria esos dos caminos implicarán un cierre de la aplicación (no puedes liberar memoria que no has reservado). Si tienes la suerte de esquivar esos dos caminos lo que sucederá es que `v.datos` no apuntará a una dirección de memoria válida... que el programa falle al acceder a dicha memoria dependerá de la suerte y de lo moderno que sea tu Sistema Operativo (los más modernos no perdonan una).

La solución es tan sencilla como inicializar las variables miembros del objeto:

```
VecDin v;
v.datos = 0;
v.n = 0;
```

Aunque como estás programando en C++, que se presupone que es orientado a objetos, lo esperable entonces es que recurras al constructor por defecto:

```
struct VecDin
{
  int *datos;
  int n;

  VecDin() : datos(0), n(0)
  { }
};
```

**Bonus final**

El estado de los `streams` no se actualiza hasta que no se realiza una lectura/escritura que provoque un error. Es decir, ante una entrada... `1 2 3 n`, este bucle:

```
int n = 1;
while(flujo.good()) {
    ReSize(v,n);
    flujo >> v.datos[n-1];
    ++n;
}
```

Va a dar como resultado la salida: `1 2 3 0`. Esto sucede porque la comprobación `flujo.good` no se está realizando en el sitio correcto. El siguiente ejemplo sería más correcto:

```
int n = 0;
int variable;
flujo >> variable;
while(flujo.good()) {
    ++n;
    ReSize(v,n);
    v.datos[n-1] = variable;
    flujo >> variable;
}
```

Ahora la lectura se realiza sobre una variable *dummy*. Si la lectura falla entonces dicho valor no se lleva a `v`.

Comment: Lo has clavado. Tambien podría inicializar v con VecDin v = {0,0} . Seria lo misno, no? Tambien le estaba dando vueltas a la salida, siempre me sacaba un dato de más. 
Muchas gracias.

Comment: @Hesterions esas inicializaciones hay que usarlas con cuidado, para hacerlo como dices yo usaría más bien `VecDin v = {nullptr,0};` para evitar posibles errores al invertir el orden de los argumentos. En este caso no pasa nada, pero si `n` tuviese un valor inicial distinto de 0 la cosa cambia...